# Отображение значений массива в новой группе UITableView (Grouped)

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Добрый день.  Есть массив, отображается через UITableView в виде списка.

Мне надо, чтоб каждое из значений в массиве отображалось в новой группе. Подскажите, как это сделать.

p.s. Я перекопал весь инет, ни одного руководства.

Comment: Есть понятие группированный список, а есть понятие секций. Вы, что подразумеваете под словом группа?

Comment: Думаю, секцию он имеет ввиду.

Comment: да именно секции, спасибо за уточнения

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос (`array` - ваш массив):

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [array count];
}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     ... //создаем или подгружаем неиспользуемую ячейку

     cell.textLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];// у нас массив строк
     return cell;

}
```